# LGPL3 library in Apache 2.0 licensed library

Tags: license-compatibility, apache-2.0, lgpl

Can I open source my project under Apache 2 if it uses a LGPL3 library without modifying it? I'm not planning to distribute the LGPL3 library along with the code.

My understanding is that LGPL3 allows this type of use, but I'm not sure if Apache 2 allows this, on the other hand since no other open souce code is actually distributed with this project, can Apache 2 prevent merely linking/referencing against LGPL3 library?

Answer (score 1):

> Can I open source my project under Apache 2 if it uses a LGPL3 library without modifying it? I'm not planning to distribute the LGPL3 library along with the code.

I would be OK with this. This is a common pattern. My Apache-licensed code can depend on an unmodified LGPL-licensed library when it dynamically links with it.

> My understanding is that LGPL3 allows this type of use,

I would be OK with this too. My LGPL3-licensed code can depend on an Apache-licensed library. In this case, my Apache-licensed code may be subject to the LGPL3 terms in general.

> but I'm not sure if Apache 2 allows this, on the other hand since no other open source code is actually distributed with this project, can Apache 2 prevent merely linking/referencing against LGPL3 library?

As I said above, I am able to link to an LGPL3-licensed library from my Apache-licensed code that can stay Apache-licensed.